# Cannot clone GIT repository on network drive

Tags: windows, git, version-control, tortoisegit, git-clone

Using Windows 7, we have a bare GIT repository set up on a network drive so that multiple users can pull/push from it.  I am able to create a new working repo on my local and multiple other networked drives.  However, when I try to clone a new working repository on the same network drive (different folder) , it fails.

Using TortoiseGIT, after I right-click and choose "GIT Clone", put in all of the necessary paths to my bare repo (the new working repo is already filled in) and hit ok, I get the following error:

```
Cloning into 'R:\path\to\new\repo'... done. 
error: refs/remotes/origin/master does not point to a valid object! 
error: Trying to write ref refs/heads/master with nonexistent object 5d2164db2c61efc7a5598f6ff75ed3fbbb12456e 
fatal: Cannot update the ref 'HEAD'. 
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128)
```

and it fails to create the repo.  It does however build the new folder & ".git" subfolder structure.

It's not a r/w permissions issue because I can r/w any other files, but just cannot seem to create this newly cloned repo.  My co-worker cannot either.  Even if I got to another folder on the network drive, I still cannot clone the repo successfully.  Surprisingly, if I just copy/paste a repo I created in another location, then manually do a "pull", it works and updates successfully.

Any ideas on what to try next?  Obviously I've Googled "exit code 128" and "cannot update the ref 'HEAD'" but cannot find a solution to my issue.  It's probably something really simple that we are overlooking, but we're just getting started with GIT and this is really causing us headaches...

**UPDATE:** I just noticed that when I do a manual pull from GIT to my "copy", it is doing a Fast-Forward.  Maybe this provides some additional clues?

```
From R:/path/to/repo
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating 5d2164d..d75bdb7
Fast-forward
Files.py |    3 +++
1 file changed, 3 insertions(+)
Success
```

Comment: This looks like the repo you are trying to clone is broken. What about the ref id given in the error message? Is it the correct HEAD, does it exist?

Comment: @Chronial, how would I identify that the ref id is correct in the HEAD?  Like I said, I am really new to this.  Thanks for your advice!

Comment: run `git log 5d2164db2c61efc7a5598f6ff75ed3fbbb12456e` in the main repo and see whether it fails. But if you can clone it to another dir, it’s probably correct.

Answer (score 9):

Git might be trying to do some smart stuff with hardlinks that fails on the network drive. Try using `git clone --no-hardlinks /r/path/to/my/repo` or `git clone file:///r/path/to/my/repo`

Answer (score -2):

Please do this via command line in msysgit

```
git clone /r/path/to/my/repo /r/some/other/path
```

Further, I would recommend using git from the command line as it is a tool that was designed to be used from the command line. You will be able to find more help, faster, with any issues that come up for you.

Comment: This is the same as what TortoiseGIT runs, just from the command line.  The error message returned (as shown in my original question) is exactly the same.  It doesn't solve the inherent issue with the "nonexistent object".

Comment: interesting. How about using the file:/// protocol instead of just the paths? You would only use it instead of the first path.